# How many times an MLB team has won a game with no hits?

Tags: baseball, trivia, history, mlb, records

The Los Angeles Dodgers and Pittsburgh Pirates tied 0-0 at the end of the 9th inning on August 23rd 2017. With one out and a runner on the second base, the pirates had a chance to win the game with no hits in the 9th. Dodgers' pitcher Rich Hill went on to throw a no hitter game through 9 innings.

The commentators mentioned that winning without a hit is a rarity, so I'm wondering how many times it has happened in MLB history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From an [ESPN article](http://www.espn.com/mlb/columns/story?columnist=kurkjian_tim&id=3465888) and [MLB article](http://m.mlb.com/news/article/3025096//) about a game between the Dodgers and Angels played in 2008:

> The final score was 1-0, marking the fifth time since 1900 that a team
>   did not get a hit but won the game.

Complete List:

```
  Cnt Date          Tm   Opp GmReslt  PA  AB  R  H 2B 3B HR RBI BB IBB SO HBP SH SF ROE GDP SB CS LOB Batrs
+----+-------------+---+----+-------+---+---+--+--+--+--+--+---+--+---+--+---+--+--+---+---+--+--+---+-----+
    1 1992-04-12(1) CLE  BOS W  2-1   32  25  2  0  0  0  0   2  7   0  6   0  0  0   1   0  6  1   6     9 

    2 1990-07-01    CHW  NYY W  4-0   31  26  4  0  0  0  0   0  5   0  3   0  0  0   3   0  1  1   3    11 

    3 1967-04-30(1) DET @BAL W  2-1   40  24  2  0  0  0  0   0 10   1  3   2  4  0   1   1  1  0  11    14 

    4 1964-04-23    CIN @HOU W  1-0   31  29  1  0  0  0  0   0  2   0  9   0  0  0   2   0  0  0   3    10 

    5 2008-06-28    LAD  LAA W  1-0   29  24  1  0  0  0  0   1  3   0  9   1  0  1   1   0  1  0   4    13
```

Source: [Baseball Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/blog/archives/10736.html) (Included code is of respective website.)

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Major_League_Baseball_no-hitters) on these win:

> five times a team has been no-hit and still won the game: two notable victories occurred when the Cincinnati Reds defeated the Houston Colt .45s (now called the Houston Astros) 1–0 on April 23, 1964 even though they were no-hit by Houston starter Ken Johnson, and the Detroit Tigers defeated the Baltimore Orioles 2–1 on April 30, 1967 even though they were no-hit by Baltimore starter Steve Barber and reliever Stu Miller.

Another list that may be helpful from [Baseball Reference](https://www.baseball-reference.com/play-index/share.fcgi?id=HrO9b).

Answer (score 1):

When the Cincinnati Reds played the Pittsburgh Pirates at PNC Park on [May 15, 2022](https://www.mlb.com/gameday/reds-vs-pirates/2022/05/15/662519#game_state=final,lock_state=final,game_tab=wrap,game=662519), Hunter Green and Art Warren combined for 8 innings with no hits, but Cincinnati lost the game 1-0 after three walks and an RBI fielders choice grounder.

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. This is not a no-hitter as defined by the MLB, as Pittsburgh did not pitch nine innings. It does answer the question, as the only requirement is "no hits" rather than a no-hitter.

Comment: Made a few more edits.  I did change the date format, which normally we wouldn't do, but this is such an american-nearly-only sport that it seemed more appropriate - if you care strongly about the date I don't mind reverting it.